# Logic App: SQL Query Returns XML as JSON challenge

Tags: sql, json, xml, logic

My SQL query returns XML data in SQL Server (with For XML). When I execute the query (Execute a SQL Query) in Logic Apps it returns the XML as JSON. I need to pass the XML to a Dynamics 365 integration in Logic Apps with a HTTP Post.

The query is (I removed the subqueries)

```
select 
    [JOURNALBATCHNUMBER],
                    [JOURNALNAME],
                    [DESCRIPTION],
                    [PAYMENTFILEID],
                    [BATCHTOTALFROMSOURCEREAL],
from ait.ImportMSSPaymentJournal for xml raw  ('CUSTOMERPAYMENTJOURNALHEADERENTITY'), type, elements
```

The action output (without all the XML):

```
    "body": {
        "ResultSets": {
            "Table1": [
                {
                    "": "<CUSTOMERPAYMENTJOURNALHEADERENTITY><JOURNALBATCHNUMBER>A-1234</JOURNALBATCHNUMBER><JOURNALNAME>MSS</JOURNALNAME><DESCRIPTION>Customer Payment-Mass Payer</DESCRIPTION><PAYMENTFILEID>MSS - May 17 2021  6:00PM</PAYMENTFILEID><BATCHTOTALFROMSOURCEREAL>10685.830000</BATCHTOTALFROMSOURCEREAL><CUSTOMERPAYMENTJOURNALLINEENTITY><JOURNALBATCHNUMBER>A-1234</JOURNALBATCHNUMBER><LINENUMBER>494</LINENUMBER><ACCOUNTDISPLAYVALUE>000200000701</ACCOUNTDISPLAYVALUE><ACCOUNTTYPE>Cust</ACCOUNTTYPE><BANKTRANSACTIONTYPE>Check</BANKTRANSACTIONTYPE><COMPANY>XX</COMPANY><CREDITAMOUNT>6800.000000</CREDITAMOUNT><CURRENCYCODE>USD</CURRENCYCODE><CUSTOMERNAME /><DEBITAMOUNT>0.000000</DEBITAMOUNT><OFFSETACCOUNTDISPLAYVALUE>US2969</OFFSETACCOUNTDISPLAYVALUE><OFFSETACCOUNTTYPE>Bank</OFFSETACCOUNTTYPE><OFFSETCOMPANY>XX</OFFSETCOMPANY><PAYMENTMETHODNAME>Check</PAYMENTMETHODNAME><POSTINGPROFILE>GEN</POSTINGPROFILE><AUTOSETTLED>No</AUTOSETTLED><BILLYEAR>2020</BILLYEAR><NSFGROUPID /><PT
                }
            ]
        },
        "OutputParameters": {}
    }
}
```

What I don't know is how do I reference the XML in the HTTP Post? Do I need to transform the JSON to XML? Or Use a different LA action to execute the query?

Thanks very much!

Tom

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1):

The correct notation to reference the result set from the query action eluded me for awhile. What finally worked, using the example above, is

`body('MyQuery')?['resultsets']?['Table1']?[0]?['']`